# delta lake - Insert into sql in pyspark is failing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, google-cloud-dataproc, delta-lake

Dataproc cluster is create with image `2.0.x` with delta io package `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0`

Spark version is 3.1.1

Spark shell initiated with :

```sh
pyspark --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
```

Command executed to create delta table and insert into delta sql's:

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer(
             c_id Long, c_name String, c_city String
             )
           USING DELTA LOCATION 'gs://edw-bi-dev-dataexports/delta-table-poc/dt_poc/customer'
         """)

spark.sql("INSERT INTO customer VALUES(1, 'Shawn', 'Tx')")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 719, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.sql.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/collection/Seq;Lscala/Option;)V
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis.$anonfun$normalizeQueryColumns$1(DeltaAnalysis.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis.org$apache$spark$sql$delta$DeltaAnalysis$$normalizeQueryColumns(DeltaAnalysis.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DeltaAnalysis.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DeltaAnalysis.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis.apply(DeltaAnalysis.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaAnalysis.apply(DeltaAnalysis.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:615)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:610)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
```

I am not able to figure out the root cause for the problem here.

Answer (score 8):

It's caused by [this change](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/a082f4600b1cb814442beed1b578bc3430a257a7#diff-cf96171d13fd77e670764766ae22afafbc4a396316bd758a89b60a6fe70d5b0dL150) that broke the binary compatibility for the `Alias` case class.  The fix for that either downgrade the Spark version to 3.0.x,  or wait until new Delta version is released with support for 3.1.x.

P.S. There are other places in Delta that were broken by changes in the Spark 3.1.1

Update (May 2021) Version 1.0.0 now is fully compatible with Spark 3.1

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. Bumping to 1.0.0 fixes the problem!