# PySpark Delta Table - generate symlink [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError]

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena, presto, delta-lake, python-poetry

I have the current situation:

- Delta table located in `S3`
- I want to query this table via `Athena`
- `spark` version `3.1.1` and `hadoop` `3.2.0`

To do this, I need to follow the docs: [instructions](https://docs.delta.io/0.7.0/presto-integration.html) and [s3 setup](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#amazon-s3)

I am using a `MacBook Pro` and with `Environment variables configured in my ~/.zshrc` for my small little `POC`:

```sh
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=<poetry_python_path>/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER=<poetry_python_path>/bin/python3
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home"
export SPARK_HOME=<poetry_python_path>/site-packages/pyspark
export PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE=1
```

I setup a small `pyspark` project, where I create my `spark_session`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import findspark
import boto3


def create_session() -> SparkSession:
    findspark.init()

    spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("delta_session") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()

    sparkContext = spark_session.sparkContext

    boto_default_session = boto3.setup_default_session()

    boto_session = boto3.Session(
        botocore_session=boto_default_session, profile_name="dev", region_name="eu-west-1"
    )
    credentials = boto_session.get_credentials()

    print(
        f"Hadoop version = {sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion()}"
    )

    hadoopConfiguration = sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hadoopConfiguration.set(
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", 
        "com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider"
    )
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", credentials.access_key)
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", credentials.secret_key)
    hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

    return spark_session
```

I then run:

```
spark_session = create_session()

from delta.tables import *

delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark_session, "s3a://<my-path-to-delta-table>")

# This works
df = delta_table.toDF()
print(df.show(10))

# This fails
delta_table.generate("symlink_format_manifest")
```

1. I am able to retrieve the delta files and create a `DataFrame`, all looks good.
2. I then try to call `delta_table.generate` and I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/run.py", line 33, in 
> delta_table.generate("symlink_format_manifest")
> File "/private/var/folders/c8/sj3rz_k14cs58nqwr3m9zsxc0000gq/T/spark-ba2ce53e-c9f8-49d4-98d5-21d9581b05f4/userFiles-b6d820f0-4e96-4e27-8808-a14b9e93928a/io.delta_delta-core_2.12-0.7.0.jar/delta/tables.py", line 74, in generate
> File "<poetry_python_path>/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in **call**
> File "<poetry_python_path>/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
> File "<poetry_python_path>/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.generate.
> : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$.apply$default$6()Z
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.$anonfun$generatePartitionPathExpression$1(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:350)
> at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
> at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
> at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.generatePartitionPathExpression(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:349)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.generatePartitionPathExpression$(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:345)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifest$.generatePartitionPathExpression(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.withRelativePartitionDir(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:338)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.writeManifestFiles(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:262)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.$anonfun$generateFullManifest$1(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:180)
> at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withJobDescription(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:53)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:32)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:27)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifest$.withStatusCode(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.$anonfun$recordManifestGeneration$1(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:365)
> at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:77)
> at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation$(DatabricksLogging.scala:67)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifest$.recordOperation(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:89)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifest$.recordDeltaOperation(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.recordManifestGeneration(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:364)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.generateFullManifest(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:167)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifestImpl.generateFullManifest$(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:165)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.hooks.GenerateSymlinkManifest$.generateFullManifest(GenerateSymlinkManifest.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeltaGenerateCommand$.$anonfun$modeNameToGenerationFunc$1(DeltaGenerateCommand.scala:58)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeltaGenerateCommand$.$anonfun$modeNameToGenerationFunc$1$adapted(DeltaGenerateCommand.scala:58)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.DeltaGenerateCommand.run(DeltaGenerateCommand.scala:50)
> at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeGenerate(DeltaTableOperations.scala:54)
> at io.delta.tables.execution.DeltaTableOperations.executeGenerate$(DeltaTableOperations.scala:48)
> at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.executeGenerate(DeltaTable.scala:45)
> at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.generate(DeltaTable.scala:176)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I call the application with:

```sh
    poetry run spark-submit --packages "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0" --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore" run.py
```

**What I tried:**

- I have tried running it without `poetry` and directly downloading spark and doing it that way
- I tried with an older `hadoop` version since they seem to use that [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#-configuration)
- I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106096/delta-lake-insert-into-sql-in-pyspark-is-failing-with-java-lang-nosuchmethoder) but it did not help me
- I have also tried `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0`
- I have verified that `delta` version `0.7.0` and `0.8.0` should support `spark 3.1.1`
- I also tried adding `pyarrow` and setting it via: `spark_session.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")`
- I have also tried to add [hadoop-common 3.2.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/3.2.0) `--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.2.0`, but that did not help either
- I also tried running it with `spark 3.1.1 and hadoop 3.2.0` but I gave it `--packages "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.7"` instead, but that gave me the error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:io.delta.tables.DeltaTable.forPath.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100M"
```

It looks to me like the `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$.apply$default$6()Z` is not callable for some reason. And I can't find anything more to install?

My `pyproject.toml`

```sh
[tool.poetry]
name = "..."
version = "1.0.0"
description = "..."
authors = ["..."]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.7.8"
pre-commit = "^2.8.2"
pyspark = {version="3.1.1", optional=true, extras=["sql"]}
findspark = "^1.4.2"
boto3 = "*"
pyarrow = "3.0.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "6.1.1"
ipdb = "0.13.3"
pytest-cov = "2.10.1"
```

Greatful for anyone potentially encountering the same issue.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment from Alex, I resolved the issue by:

- Spark version `3.0.2`
- Hadoop version `3.2.0`
- Delta `0.8.0`
- `spark-submit --packages "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0" --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore" ~/code/dataops-delta-infrastructure/run.py`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to downgrade Spark to Spark 3.0.2 to use Delta 0.8.0 - unfortunately, Spark 3.1.1 made many changes in the internal things that are used Delta under the hood, and this breaks the binary compatibility.  Most probably, your specific problem is caused by [SPARK-32154](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32154) that made changes in the parameters of the `ScalaUDF` (this [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/004aea8155d3b768684ab20cd29b3a820a204f22#diff-adaf27cbb8328e0b9665c62cfeb8973d0cd51e6984e7596134a44936ed39f16fR52))

Comment: Thank you Alex, this saved my day! And was impossible for me to find in the docs, since they say it should be compatible here:

https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html

Comment: yeah, I was hit by this incompatibility myself, and waiting for release compatible with 3.1

Comment: do you know if this supports `3.1.1` yet?

Comment: as I understand it will be soon, but can't say precisely. The code is already in git, so you can compile yourself